# Access file cross domain with JavaScript without server sided implementation

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain

Is there any way to access a file from another domain through JavaScript without any server side implementations?

I'm trying to read a text file from a webserver and save the content to a variable. I want to process the content later on.

But any XMLHttpRequest based operations seem to violate the same [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  And since I do not have access to the server, I can not use anything like a webservice that returns the content to my JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have no access to `THE server` that contains the file or generally no access to `A server` suitable to run a server side implementation? I think easiest would be a little server side proxy script on your domain that pulls the file from the other domain. You could do this easily in PHP with a few lines of code.

Comment: @Nic I do not have access to the server that hosts the file. I try to access the file from a WebApp running on a mobile device. But right now I'm testing from my local webserver (IIS).